# Can't access file even though I am the user, I have permissions, I have chowned/chmod'd the entire directory structure, selinux off

Tags: permissions, rhel, acl

Sorry for the copy/paste, doing this over a remote screen share:

[image]

I am on Rocky Linux and I am at a total loss as to what is going on here. I can't cat/vim this file but as you can see, I am the owner, and I gave it 775. I have also chmod'd the entire directory structure (with -R) and chown'd (with -R) the entire directory structure leading to this file to ensure there isn't some weird thing where a parent folder's permissions are the problem.

[image]

I even checked to make sure there wasn't some weird ACL going on here and for good measure turned off SELinux. Nothing - the file is untouchable by anything other than root.

What else could be causing this if it's not permissions, ACLs, or SELinux?

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please read the first sentence of the post.

Comment: Several screen share clients still allow you to cut/paste text. Other option may be to actually log into the remote server to cut/paste or ask the remote user to cut/paste and email to you. Not exercising any of these options will make it difficult for us to help you. And have you checked `getacl` on the file?

Comment: The dot at the end of the permissions means the files [have SELinux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30594957/6005145), that may be the issue then. The answer in SO I linked says: `you can set or delete ACL association for a file by using the setfacl command`.